# HTML form to generate an URL with special character and prefix between parameter name and value

Tags: html, forms, url

Could an ordinal HTML form that generates a GET request, produce such an URL **without JavaScript**?:

```
http://servername/urlpart1/#/urlpart2?id=Prefix-139
```

where `http://servername/urlpart1/#/urlpart2?id=Prefix-` is constant and 139 ist an `<input name="id" />` value.

I could achieve only the URL generation:

- without `#` character and
- with `id=139`, without `Prefix`.

---

```
<form action="http://servername/urlpart1/urlpart2">
  <input name="id" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Update**

I ended up with building a small desktop Windows application where I can do whatever I want.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could add the value attribute to `<input name="id">` and give it the value `Prefix-`, so the user could just type in the value after it. Maybe also use some pattern matching and display an error if the user deleted that piece of text. The below code only shows adding the `value` attribute, not the pattern matching.

```
<form action="http://servername/urlpart1/#/urlpart2">
  <input name="id" value = "Prefix-" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to manipulate the action URL without using JS, however, you could require the "Prefix-" as part of your "id" field's pattern.

Try something like this:

```
<form action="http://servername/urlpart1/#/urlpart2" method="GET">
    <input name="id" value="Prefix-" pattern="Prefix-+[0-9]{1,}" title="Prefix-{number}." />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My pattern example requires the string "Prefix-" followed by at least 1 numeric value.

Comment: Thank you. But what to do with the pound sign?

Comment: @Paul, have you tried encoding the pound sign in your URL? Try this: `http://servername/urlpart1/%23/urlpart2`

Comment: Yes I did. Unfortunately server does not accept such a format.

Comment: Ugh, that's a bummer. I've seen the pound sign used when referencing an anchor tag, but not in the way you're using it. Is it doing something specific?

Comment: @Paul, have you tried using something like bitly.com to create a URL you can use?

Comment: This is our internal URL and is not allowed to be published for security reasons. When it comes to passing the URL through a server then it'd better our server. But I think I'd better make some JavaScript when the native way isn't possible.

Comment: Sorry, I ended up with building a small desktop Windows application where I can do whatever I want.

Comment: @Paul, don't you hate it when you have to resort to something like that? Curious though, why no JS?

Comment: Because of two reasons: 1. Vivaldi browser and some other browsers block JS for local documents with "file://" schema. In order to use it I should make my own local web server, and I do not want this. 2. Now I have a Win32 tool that could be called quickly by key combination defined in Windows shortcut, no matter which application is currently active. I enter an article number and am navigated to it quickly.